# Android Null Pointer Excpetion in Login

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, xmpp

Here is my Code (the activity). Im having a problem with the `conn.login` method returning a null pointer exception. I dont seem to understand what the problem is.

```
Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                EditText userN = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
                String inputUsername = userN.getText().toString(); // get the username input and store it in inputUsername

                EditText userP = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
                String inputPassword = userP.getText().toString(); // get the password input and store it in inputPassword

                XMPP conn = new XMPP("192.168.1.90", inputUsername, inputPassword);
                //XMPPTCPConnection connection;

                conn.connect(); // connect to server



                try {

                        conn.login(conn.connection, inputUsername, inputPassword); // login problem here, code line 117.

                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MyActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);

            }
        });
```

Here is my xmpp `class` file.

```
public class XMPP{
private String serverAddress = "192.168.1.90";
private int portNumber = 5222;
public XMPPTCPConnection connection;
private String loginUser;
private String passwordUser;
public String userStatus;


//-------------Constructor----------------
public XMPP(String serverAddress, String loginUser, String passwordUser){
    this.serverAddress = serverAddress;
    this.loginUser = loginUser;
    this.passwordUser = passwordUser;
}

public void connect(){
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> connectionThread = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>(){
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0){
            boolean isConnected = false;
            ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration( serverAddress, portNumber);
            config.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
            connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
            XMPPConnectionListener  connectionListener = new XMPPConnectionListener();
            connection.addConnectionListener(connectionListener);

            config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);

            try{
                connection.connect();
                isConnected = true;
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SmackException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XMPPException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return isConnected;
        }
    };
    connectionThread.execute();
}

public void login(XMPPConnection connection, String loginUser, String passwordUser){

    this.loginUser = loginUser;
    this.passwordUser = passwordUser;

    try{

        connection.login(loginUser, passwordUser); //logcat takes me here line 93.


    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e)
    {
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                connect();
            }
        }, 5 * 1000);
    } catch (SaslException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XMPPException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SmackException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public class XMPPConnectionListener implements ConnectionListener{
    @Override
    public void connected(final XMPPConnection connection){
        if(!connection.isAuthenticated())
            login(connection, loginUser, passwordUser); 
    }
    @Override
    public void authenticated(XMPPConnection arg0){}
    @Override
    public void connectionClosed(){}
    @Override
    public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception arg0){}
    @Override
    public void reconnectingIn(int arg0){}
    @Override
    public void reconnectionFailed(Exception arg0){}
    @Override
    public void reconnectionSuccessful(){}
    }
}
```

and here is my logcat...

```
Reconstruct Branch:
02-13 00:00:01.995  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
02-13 00:00:03.977  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
02-13 00:00:03.977  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
02-13 00:00:04.087  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
02-13 00:00:09.112  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
02-13 00:00:09.122  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
02-13 00:00:12.696  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
02-13 00:00:12.696  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.haz.project1.XMPP.login(XMPP.java:93)
02-13 00:00:12.706  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.haz.project1.Login$2.onClick(Login.java:117)
02-13 00:00:12.706  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
02-13 00:00:12.706  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
02-13 00:00:12.706  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-13 00:00:12.706  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-13 00:00:12.706  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
02-13 00:00:12.706  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
02-13 00:00:12.706  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 00:00:12.706  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-13 00:00:12.706  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
02-13 00:00:12.706  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
02-13 00:00:12.706  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-13 00:00:12.776  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
02-13 00:00:12.776  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
02-13 00:00:12.846  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
02-13 00:00:12.866  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
02-13 00:00:12.866  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
02-13 00:00:12.866  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
02-13 00:00:12.866  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
02-13 00:00:12.876  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
02-13 00:00:12.916  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
02-13 00:00:12.916  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
02-13 00:00:12.916  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
02-13 00:00:12.956  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
02-13 00:00:12.966  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
02-13 00:01:18.820  17160-17160/com.example.haz.project1 D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `conn.connect();` on the xmpp instance.
Within this method, you are creating an asynchronous task,which gets executed directly.

The main thread tries to use the `conn.login(...);` directly after starting the thread.
You are trying to access the connection object inside the login function by calling **its** login function (unfortunate duplicated naming here).
The variable is still null, because your AsyncTask did not finish (and set it) yet.
(It may not even have started.)

If possible, try to connect if you want to log in, not before.
Then do **all** the networking stuff in an AsyncTask in order to not block the main-UI-thread.

1. User Clicks Button
2. New AsyncTask will be started

   4. Try to connect (try again if not working)
   5. login
   6. report back to UI in AsyncTak's `onPostExecute`

This does not block the UI thread.

### Note:

Why dont you make connection in the XMPP class private ? 
You are only using it in the login function, which is part of the XMPP class. Also then you just have to call `conn.login(username,password)`